# How is this array initialised to zero?

Tags: c

How exactly is the binary hash map working here? As in, how does it initialise only `binMap[elements in arr]` to `1` and the rest to `0`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100000

void printPairs(int arr[], int arr_size, int sum)
{
  int i, temp;
  bool binMap[MAX] = {0}; /*initialize hash map as 0*/

  for(i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
  {
    temp = sum - arr[i];
    if(temp >= 0 && binMap[temp] == 1)
    {
      printf("Pair with given sum %d is (%d, %d) \n", sum, arr[i], temp);
    }
    binMap[arr[i]] = 1;
  }
}

int main()
{
    int A[] = {1, 4, 45, 6, 10, 8};
    int n = 16;
    int arr_size = 6;

    printPairs(A, arr_size, n);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> As in how does it initialise only binMap[elements in arr] to 1 and the
>   rest to 0?

With this

```
bool binMap[MAX] = {0};
```

The every element in the array `binMap` array is initialized to `0` (actually it sets only `binMap[0]` to `0` but due to implicit initialization in C, the rest of the elements are set to `0` too) at first.

Then with this in the loop,

```
binMap[arr[i]] = 1;
```

the indexes given by the elements of `arr` are set to 1. For example, if `arr[i]` is `45` then `binMap[45]` is set to `1`.